# paper.js canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Пишу простенькую онлайн игру на основе canvas. Столкнулся с проблемой, после нажатия кнопки (обычный button вне canvas) отправляется какой-то ajax запрос, и после получения ответа нужно отобразить текст ответа в canvas. Но, что бы на canvas обновился, нужно навести на него курсор, без этого ничего не происходит.

Значит ли это, что все должно быть построено только с помощью canvas? Или же как победить мою проблему...

Текст (на холсте больше ничего нет)

```
centerText = new PointText({
        point: path.bounds.center,
        content: 'TEST',
        fillColor: '#000',
        fontFamily: 'Courier New',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 20,
        justification: 'center'
    });
```

Comment: А что вам мешает отрисовать кадр по нажатию на кнопку, а не по наведению курсора?

Comment: @Darth никаких кадров нет, обычная статика, с использованием `PointText`. На холсте расположен только один текст и все

Answer (score 1):

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.height=window.innerHeight-20;
canvas.width=document.body.clientWidth-350;
var c2d=canvas.getContext('2d');
document.getElementById('button').onclick=function(){
    c2d.fillText('Problem?',100,100);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<button id="button">
click
</button>
```

Comment: Потому не зря упомянул paper.js =)

Comment: @JILeXanDR Зачем использовать то, что не работает? Кроме того, что вам мешает применять VanillaJS там где paper.js не справляется, и при этом продолжать использовать полезные фичи paper.js?

Comment: мне кажется проще найти проблему, чем городить кучу кода на VanillaJS